# ActiveMQ - Consuming from Queue and Topic at the same time

Tags: activemq-classic

We are trying to consume messages in activemq. The producer (of which we have no control) puts the different messages in a Queue and a Topic. As a consumer how could I configure my client to consume from the queue and the topic concurrently? The only way I can think of is to create two different consumers, one connected to the queue and the other connected to the topic. 
Is this approach correct or is there something that I could do to create one consumer that listens to both at the same time?

Thanks
K

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much the way to go, two listeners for the two endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ standard distribution comes bundled with Apache Camel.

Given that you are running the standard ActiveMQ - you could add a small route to Camel that does this for you.

Edit the "camel.xml" int the /conf folder.

Add two routes:

```
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:topic:someTopic"/>
  <to uri="activemq:queue:comboQueue"/>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:someQueue"/>
  <to uri="activemq:queue:comboQueue"/>
</route>
```

Make sure this camel.xml is included in the ActiveMQ config, such as Activemq.xml.

Now, just consume from "comboQueue" and you get all messages in one place.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the activemq instance that we are using (as a consumer) is installed on a machine that we dont control. All we have control of is the broker connection URL. We wont be able to change any activemq configuration. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Na. you can't do much then. You need to setup two listeners. However, you could of course run a local ActiveMQ instance with the above Camel config to merge the two different destinations to a local queue. Just configure a conncetion factory in ActiveMQ to the remote ActiveMQ instance.

`<from uri="remoteAMQ:queue:someQueue"/>
<to uri="activemq:queue:comboQueue"/>`

That might be trickier and more complex than simply put up two listeners though..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using ActiveMQ's [composite destination](http://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations.html) feature which allows you to listen on more than one destination and on differet types of destinations.